How can I retrieve Youtube Clip info from the Youtube API?
I'm trying to get a similar response to Videos: list endpoint of the Youtube API, but for youtube clips instead of videos. The data I'm looking for specifically is title, views, uploader, thumbnail, duration, embed url. A Youtube video has a URL like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Q_ZzBGPdqE, while a youtube clip has a URL like this: https://youtube.com/clip/UgkxJKmfKeQYLM9ex5qrU-W2wkwLCfRvlgYU
The string after /clip/ seems to be an ID, similar to how the string after v= is the video ID for youtube videos. However there seems to be no clip specific API, and the videos API does not accept the clip ID. Is there some dedicated clips API or support for clips in one of the APIs that I'm missing?
I've tried using this API with any of the seemingly relevant Youtube API endpoints, but they just return empty responses.
There are also methods to get the parent video ID of the clip (such as the API provided in this answer). I could then use that parent video id to call the youtube videos API. This would give some useful information as it would be the same between the parent video and the clip (uploader, thumbnail). But other information that I'm looking for is clip specific and would not be provided in that response (title, views, duration, embed url)

The Stack Overflow answer 71550460 proceeds more precisely than 78961552.

This question is similar to: Method to extract details from YouTube Clip. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@DarkBee I've updated the question

@BenjaminLoison With your API I see I can get the clip title and duration, and then using the video id I could get the thumbnail and uploader. Clip views would be nice but not absolutely necessary, I am stuck on the embed url though. The embed url for the example clip is this: https://www.youtube.com/embed/V77X_CINsrU?clip=UgkxJKmfKeQYLM9ex5qrU-W2wkwLCfRvlgYU&clipt=EPumBhiqkQg.   I can construct most of this URL using the clip id and parent video id, but I'm stuck on how to derive the clipt query param value

Concerning clipt does the question 74697206 and its comments meet your needs?

@slink58 I just added the viewCount you requested, see https://github.com/Benjamin-Loison/YouTube-operational-API/commit/0e4168e9ed307cc760f1fe4d69aa8143a4a66ba1.

@BenjaminLoison ooh nice, so looks I can protobuf encode the startTimeMs and endTimeMs to get the clipt, going to play around with this. And that's awesome on the view count thank you!

The v= value (video_id) can be found in the html content. Here's an example of how to extract it using Python:
import requests

def extract_video_id_from_html(html_content):
    # split on 'video_id='
    partsA = html_content.split('video_id=')
    if len(partsA) >= 2:
        # split on double quote
        partsB = partsA[1].split('"')
        if len(partsB) >= 1:
            return partsB[0]

# make request
response = requests.get('https://youtube.com/clip/UgkxJKmfKeQYLM9ex5qrU-W2wkwLCfRvlgYU')

# extract video_id from html content
video_id = extract_video_id_from_html(response.text)

print(video_id) # V77X_CINsrU

# constuct url for YouTube API:
youtube_video_url = f'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v={video_id}'


Right, this would get the parent video id from the clip, and I could then use that to call the youtube videos API. That would just give me information on the parent video though. Some of that info will be useful as it will be the same for both the video and the clip (uploader, thumbnail), but other info is different for the clip (title, duration, views)
